# How to extract a set of rows from one column of a dataframe using a variable column header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of multiple columns: the first is 'qty' and contains several (usually 4) replicates for several different quantities. The remaining columns represent the result of a test for the corresponding replicate at the corresponding quantity -- either a numeric value or a string ('TND' for target not detected, 'Ind' for indeterminate, etc.). Each of the columns (other than the first) represent the results for given 'targets', and there can be any number of targets in a given dataset. An example might be

```
qty   target1     target2
 1      TND         TND
 1      724         TND
 1      TND         TND
 1      674         TND
 5      1.4E+04     TND
 5      9.2E+03     194
 5      1.1E+04     TND
 5      9.9E+03     TND
```

The ultimate goal is to get the probability of detecting each target at each concentration/quantity, so I initially calculated this using the function

```
def hitrate(qty,df):
   t_s = df[df.qty == qty].result
   t_s = t_s.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)).isna()
   return (len(t_s)-t_s.sum())/len(t_s)
```

but this was when I only needed to evaluate probabilities for a single target. Before calling `hitrate`, I'd just ask the user what the header for their target column was, assign it to the variable `tar`, and use `df = df.rename(columns={tar:'result'})`.

Now that there are multiple targets, I can't use the `hitrate` function I wrote, as I need to call it in a loop such as

```
qtys = df['qty'].unique()
probs = np.zeros([len(qtys),len(targets)])
for i, tar in targets:
   for idx, val in enumerate(qtys):
      probs[idx,i] = hitrate(val,data)
```

But the `hitrate` function explicitly pulls the result/target column for a given quantity by using `df[df.qty == qty].result`. This no longer works, since the target column changes, and trying to use something like `df[df.qty == qty].targets[i]` or `df[df.qty == qty].tar` throws an error, presumably because you can't reference a dataframe column with a variable containing the column name (like you can with the column name directly, i.e. `df.result`).

In the end, I need to end up with two arrays or dataframes such as (with the above example table as reference):

```
Table for target_1:
qty   probability
 1        0.5
 5        1.0

Table for target_2:
qty   probability
 1        0.0
 5        0.25
```

I'm sorry if the question is confusing... If so, leave a comment and I'll try to be a bit clearer. It's been a long day. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `df[df.qty == qty][tar]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most [basic](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics) way of accessing a column from a `DataFrame` is to use square brackets (like a dict):

```
df['some_column']
```

[Attribute indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access) is nice, but it doesn't work in many cases (Column names with spaces, for example).

So, try something like:

```
target = 'target1'
...
df[df.qty == qty][target]
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising & I'll report back when I've had a chance to work this in & test it. Should this work even when `[target]` contains things like spaces, special characters, etc.? The targets (in the natural format) may be named ex. `"P 7/3.2"` and I'd like to keep the natural names where possible so the researchers don't have to figure out which target `'target1'` refers to. I realize I could make a separate list of names `[t1, t2, ...]` and then report the results using the name they entered, but I'm trying to avoid renaming things where possible

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you kindly!